# Discretize path with numpy array and equal distance between points

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I have a path in a 2d-plane given by a parametrization, for example the archimedian spiral:

**x(t) = a*φ*cos(φ)**,  **y(t) = a*φ*sin(φ)**

Im looking for a way to discretize this with a numpy array,
the problem is if I use

```
a = 1
phi = np.arange(0, 10*np.pi, 0.1)
x = a*phi*np.cos(phi)
y = a*phi*np.sin(phi)
plt.plot(x,y, "ro")
```

I get a nice curve but the points don't have the same distance, for 
growing φ the distance between 2 points gets larger.
Im looking for a nice and if possible fast way to do this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe you are right. Is it possible to move it there?

Comment: A moderator may be able to migrate it, but it's probably easier to delete this and create a new one.

Comment: Hint: do the line integral to know the length of the segment as a function of the angle. IIRC, you should use points equally spaced in log scale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be possible to get the exact analytical formula for your simple spiral, but I am not in the mood to do that and this might not be possible in a more general case. Instead, here is a numerical solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = 1
phi = np.arange(0, 10*np.pi, 0.1)
x = a*phi*np.cos(phi)
y = a*phi*np.sin(phi)

dr = (np.diff(x)**2 + np.diff(y)**2)**.5 # segment lengths
r = np.zeros_like(x)
r[1:] = np.cumsum(dr) # integrate path
r_int = np.linspace(0, r.max(), 200) # regular spaced path
x_int = np.interp(r_int, r, x) # interpolate
y_int = np.interp(r_int, r, y)

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o-')
plt.title('Original')
plt.axis([-32,32,-32,32])

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(x_int, y_int, 'o-')
plt.title('Interpolated')
plt.axis([-32,32,-32,32])
plt.show()
```

It calculates the length of all the individual segments, integrates the total path with `cumsum` and finally interpolates to get a regular spaced path. You might have to play with your step-size in `phi`, if it is too large you will see that the spiral is not a smooth curve, but instead built from straight line segments. Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a really good solution for me, exactly what I was looking for.